# Creating custom functions in Spring Boot services

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am writing a simple Spring Boot Application.I'm creating a repository,then its service and then its implementation
The code works fine if I use inbuilt functions of the JPA repository.
However it throws error if I try to make a function in the service interface.
If I make that function in the repository it doesn't throw that error
Here is the code:

```
Repository:

@Transactional
public interface Local_Repository extends JpaRepository<LocalModel,Long> {



}

Service:

public interface Local_Service {

    public List<LocalModel> findAll();
    public LocalModel findById(Long id);
    public LocalModel findBymo(String mo);//this is the function I added
}

Implementation:

@Service
public class Local_Impl implements Local_Service {

    @Autowired
    private Local_Repository repository;
    @Override
    public List<LocalModel> findAll() {
        List<LocalModel> cities = (List<LocalModel>) repository.findAll();

        return cities;

    }

    @Override
    public LocalModel findById(Long id) {
        LocalModel city = repository.findOne(id);
        return city;
    }
@Override //this throws error
public LocalModel findBymo(String mo) {
    LocalModel city=repository.findBymo(mo);

   return null;
}
```

}

Comment: Can you share LocalModel details? Anyway, if there is a filed "mo" in LocalModel then you can write your method in Local_Repository like `public LocalModel findByMo(String mo);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the service you are calling a function that doesn't exist in the repository layer. There is no method called `findBymo` in the repository. If LocalModel has a field called mo, you can just add a function in the repository interface like this

```
LocalModel findByMo(String mo);
```

and it will be implemented automatically.

If LocalModel doesn't have such field you should implement the query yourself in the repository like this

```
@Query("select ... query here")
LocalModel findByMo(String mo);
```

Comment: Since the function is not in the repository layer,it can't implement it. I had the same thought too.Thanks for helping me out man.

Comment: So I can't define it directly in services,i have to define it in repository.

Comment: yes, you have to define the missing function in the repository since you are calling the function on repository

Comment: Now I'm getting this error:java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous handler methods mapped for HTTP path 'http://localhost:8080/url

Comment: Here is a link with more info about creating custom methods in your repo. https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/2.0.5.RELEASE/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.details